# How to parse a parenthesized hierarchy root?

Tags: antlr

I'm trying to parse values with ANTLR. Here's the relevant part of my grammar:

```
root : IDENTIFIER | SELF | literal | constructor | call | indexer;

hierarchy : root (SUB^ (IDENTIFIER | call | indexer))*;

factor  : hierarchy ((MULT^ | DIV^ | MODULO^) hierarchy)*;

sum : factor ((PLUS^ | MINUS^) factor)*;

comparison  : sum (comparison_operator^ sum)*;

value   : comparison | '(' value ')';
```

I won't describe each token or rule since their name is quite explanatory of their role. This grammar works well and compiles, allowing me to parse, using `value`, things such as:

```
a.b[c(5).d[3] * e()] < e("f")
```

[image: Interpretation]

The only thing left for value recognition is to be able to have parenthesized hierarchy roots. For instance:

```
(a.b).c
(3 < d()).e
...
```

Naively, and without much expectations, I tried adding the following alternative to my `root` rule:

```
root : ... | '(' value ')';
```

This however breaks the `value` rule due to non-LL(*)ism:

```
rule value has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable
from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using 
backtrack=true option.
```

[image: Break]

Even after reading most of *The Definitive ANTLR Reference*, I still don't understand these errors. However, what I do understand is that, upon seeing a parenthesis opening, ANTLR cannot know if it's looking at the beginning of a parenthesized value, or at the beginning of a parenthesized root.

How can I clearly define the behavior of parenthesized hierarchy root?

**Edit**: As requested, the additional rules:

```
parameter : type IDENTIFIER -> ^(PARAMETER ^(type IDENTIFIER));

constructor : NEW type PAREN_OPEN (arguments+=value (SEPARATOR arguments+=value)*)? PAREN_CLOSE -> ^(CONSTRUCTOR type ^(ARGUMENTS $arguments*)?);

call : IDENTIFIER PAREN_OPEN (values+=value (SEPARATOR values+=value)*)? PAREN_CLOSE -> ^(CALL IDENTIFIER ^(ARGUMENTS $values*)?);

indexer : IDENTIFIER INDEX_START (values+=value (SEPARATOR values+=value)*)? INDEX_END -> ^(INDEXER IDENTIFIER ^(ARGUMENTS $values*));
```

Comment: could you post your complete parser file? (What's `constructor`, `call`, `indexer`, for instance?) I'm not an ANTLR Guru, but I've built things like that in the past (compilers - using Lex/Yacc for the Parser part - to be precise), and I might be able to help you.

Comment: I truly believe those are irrelevant to the question, but I will add them to the question.

Comment: Just an idea (it may seem stupid, but I'd try it if I were you) : create another element `superroot : PAREN_OPEN root PAREN_CLOSE` and see what happens. (I hoped I didn't mess up the syntax but you get my point...)

Comment: or basically : `super : PAREN_OPEN root PAREN_CLOSE | root`

Comment: I could have added `| '(' root ')'` instead of `| '(' value ')'`, but that would only allow other root elements to be parenthesized, ant not things such as `(3 < d()).e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `'(' value ')'` from `value` and place it in `root`:

```
root : IDENTIFIER | SELF | literal | constructor | call | indexer | '(' value ')';

...

value : comparison;
```

Now `(a.b).c` will result in the following parse:

[image]

And `(3 < d()).e` in:

[image]

Of course, you'll probably want to omit the parenthesis from the AST:

```
root : IDENTIFIER | SELF | literal | constructor | call | indexer | '('! value ')'!;
```

Also, you don't need to append tokens in a `List` using `+=` in your parser rules. The following:

```
call 
 : IDENTIFIER PAREN_OPEN (values+=value (SEPARATOR values+=value)*)? PAREN_CLOSE 
   -> ^(CALL IDENTIFIER ^(ARGUMENTS $values*)?)
 ;
```

can be rewritten into:

```
call 
 : IDENTIFIER PAREN_OPEN (value (SEPARATOR value)*)? PAREN_CLOSE 
   -> ^(CALL IDENTIFIER ^(ARGUMENTS value*)?)
 ;
```

### EDIT

Your main problem is the fact that certain input can be parsed in two (or more!) ways. For example, the input `(a)` could be parsed by alternative 1 and 2 of your `value` rule:

```
value 
 : comparison    // alternative 1
 | '(' value ')' // alternative 2
 ;
```

Run through your parser rules: a `comparison` (alternative 1) can match `(a)` because it matches the `root` rule, which in its turn matches `'(' value ')'`. But that is also what alternative 2 matches! And there you have it: the parser "sees" for one input, two different 
parses and reports about this ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you refer me to some explanation of how to perceive such errors and analyze them? My brain still can't get a hold of what's wrong, and thus it obviously can't fix it. (P.S.: My grammar is not optimized for beauty really yet, but thanks for the implicit list tip)

Comment: Thanks. I maintain, however, that this is in no way clear from `rule has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable
from alts 1,2`. I see no recursion in your explanation.

Comment: @LazloBonin: true. I only registered the *"alts-error"*, but that was just a part of the problem. The recursion is the fact that a `value` is also a `value` inside the parenthesis. If you remove `value` inside the literal parenthesis in both the `value`- and `root` rules, you will see that there's only a *"alts-error"*, and no mention of recursion.