# Why is there a recursion overflow in this rule?

Tags: antlr

This is a "follow-up" from this question: [How to parse a parenthesized hierarchy root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405668/how-to-parse-a-parenthesized-hierarchy-root) (Know that the `root` rule has now been renamed `atom`).

In my ANTLR grammar, I now tried adding support for casts:

```
cast : '(' type ')' atom -> ^(CAST type atom);
```

Now, I need to make it part of the value tree. Since a cast is atomic in itself, can be the base of a hierarchy, and be used in any binary operation (factors, sums, comparison), I figured it had to go in the `atom` (formerly `root`) rule.

```
cast : '(' type ')' atom -> ^(CAST type atom);

atom : cast | IDENTIFIER | SELF | literal | constructor | call | indexer | '('! value ')'!;

hierarchy : atom (SUB^ (IDENTIFIER | call | indexer))*;

factor : hierarchy ((MULT^ | DIV^ | MODULO^) hierarchy)*;

sum : factor ((PLUS^ | MINUS^) factor)*;

comparison : sum (comparison_operator^ sum)*;

value : comparison;
```

Luckily, everything seems to be LL(*) enough this time. However, I get an infinite recursion from `type` to `type`:

```
type : name=IDENTIFIER (LESSER (generics+=type (SEPARATOR generics+=type)*) GREATER)? -> ^(TYPE $name ^(GENERICS $generics*));
```

> [rule **atom**] Alternative 1 [*cast*]: after matching input such as PAREN_OPEN IDENTIFIER LESSER IDENTIFIER LESSER IDENTIFIER LESSER IDENTIFIER LESSER IDENTIFIER {LESSER, SEPARATOR} decision cannot predict what comes next due to recursion overflow to *type* from *type*

This case reflects something such as `(x<x<x<x<x[</,]`.

ANTLR's errors are quite impenetrable. I've re-read the chapter explaining this exact error and I still don't get it. What I also don't understand is that, on a standalone basis, the `type` rule never triggered any infinite recursion warning.

How can I fix it? And please, for my understanding of ANTLR, can you explain why it triggers now?

Comment: 1.4.3 Here: http://pastie.org/private/sbx5dqcofvcihboheg8vja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't go as far as saying that ANTLR's error messages are (all) impenetrable, but yeah, *this* error is...

In this case, ANTLR has a problem making a distinction between the relational expression `IDENTIFIER < atom` and `IDENTIFIER < ...` that is a part of a `type`. Both of these alternatives can be the start of an `atom` rule.

You can verify this by either changing the start of the generic-type so that it's not the same as those of the relational LT-expressions:

```
type
 : IDENTIFIER ('@' (type (',' type)*) '>')?
 ;
```

or by leaving the LT sign in the generic type, but by removing the `IDENTIFIER` from the `atom` rule:

```
type
 : IDENTIFIER ('<' (type (',' type)*) '>')?
 ;

atom
 : cast 
 //| IDENTIFIER
 | SELF
 | literal
 | constructor
 | call
 | indexer
 | '('! value ')'!
 ;
```

Both, of course, not realistic options, I know.

To make ANTLR happy with the grammar, you could add a syntactic predicate just in front of the `cast` alternative in the `atom` rule (and leave the `type` rule as you currently have it):

```
atom
 : (cast)=> cast 
 | IDENTIFIER
 | SELF
 | literal
 | constructor
 | call
 | indexer
 | '('! value ')'!
 ;
```

This forces the parser to first look ahead and make sure there *really* is a `cast` alternative to be matched, and when there's not, it falls through to the later alternatives in the `atom` rule.

But the better option here is that you don't allow your grammar to match relational expressions like:

```
a < b < c
```

which doesn't make a lot of sense: the relational expression `a < b` usually evaluates to a boolean, which cannot be compared to `c`, right? Also, you now group all logical-, relational- and equality operators in one rule, making them *all* have the same precedence: whereas in most cases, `OR` has the lowest, then comes `AND`, then equality and after that come the relational operators.

So, instead of:

```
value      : comparison;
comparison : sum (comparison_operator^ sum)?;
...

comparison_operator : EQUAL | NOT_EQUAL | GREATER | LESSER
                    | GREATER_OR_EQUAL | LESSER_OR_EQUAL 
                    | AND | OR
                    ;
```

do:

```
value : or;
or    : and (OR^ and)*;
and   : eq (AND^ eq)*;
eq    : rel ((EQUAL | NOT_EQUAL)^ rel)?; // note the '?' and no '*'
rel   : sum ((GREATER | LESSER | GREATER_OR_EQUAL | LESSER_OR_EQUAL)^ sum)?; // note the '?' and no '*'
sum   : factor ((PLUS | MINUS)^ factor)*;
...
```

and then you don't need the predicate in front of `type` in the `atom` rule *and* you have the operators precedence in the proper order.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation and suggestions. I hadn't considered the priority of relational operators, and it did bug me that things such as `a < b < c` or `a == b != c` were allowed. What's your reasoning to solve such problems?

Comment: You're welcome @LazloBonin. Not sure if I understand: you mean what my reasoning is for answering question about ANTLR, here on SO?